# Using scrapy when all data appears to be in one item with no structure

Tags: scrapy

I am scraping [this website](https://www.clevelandfed.org/publications/working-paper) to ideally get the info for each paper as a separate entry. After exploring with the scrapy shell and "View page source", all the info appears to be in the one item

```html
<div class="component site-search-results col-12 initialized rendered" data-initialize="...">
```

How can I use scrapy and xpaths to get the info for each paper with this specific website?

Here's the xpath I tried to select one paper.

```
//*[@id="content"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should using XPath like this `//div[@class="result-list"]/ul/li`
After it you shoud use all children xpath (in cycle as example) with "." prefix. Example:

```
for children_node in response.xpath('//div[@class="result-list"]/ul/li'):
    title = children_node.xpath('.//h5/text()').get()
```

For get more theory and practice about XPath you can use this sources:

1. https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html
2. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp
3. https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html